# split a string in java containing /

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, path

i split the strings below by the last / of the path:

```
html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/font/table/tbody/tr/td/p = Infoprat
html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a = 547 astuces Windows 95/98
html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/p = Infoprat
```

and i got this result :

```
html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/font/table/tbody/tr/td
html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a = 547 astuces Windows 95
html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td
```

but in the second line , because of a the / in 547 astuces Windows 95/98 , it didnt work.
how can i ignore this / in 547 astuces Windows 95/98 ?

my code is :

```
line = line.substring(0,line.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Comment: You can first split with `=` followed by splitting with `/` on the first element of the array.

Comment: yeeeees it works :D thanks paramod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string with `=` and then perform the required operations on the first element of the array returned by the `split` operation.

```
line = line.split("=")[0];
// input: html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a = 547 astuces Windows 95/98
// output: html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a
```